# How to display a detailed/specific page in React and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently building an e-commerce website as a personal project using ReactJS and Redux for the Front-end Framework and state Management. Now I've Implemented a searchbar and when I search a product (in this case a phone), i want it to direct the user to the detailed view of that respective product.

Here's the code for the following :

-----> App.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
       searchField : state.searchReducer.searchField,
       products : state.cartReducer.products
     }
   }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onSearchChange : (event) => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value))
      }
    }

class App extends Component{
render(){
const {products,searchField,onSearchChange} = this.props;

const onSearchProducts = (event) => {
  if(event.key === 'Enter'){
    console.log('The Key Presses is ',event.key);
    console.log('onSearchProducts cartItems',this.props);
    const filteredPhone = products.filter(phone => {
      return phone.pName.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
    })
    console.log('This is onSearchProducts',filteredPhone[0].pid);
    return filteredPhone[0].pid;
  }
  return null;
}

return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Navbar/>
        <Searchbar onSearchChange={onSearchChange} onSearchProducts={onSearchProducts}/>
        {/* <div className='dib w-100'>
          <Homepage />
        </div> */}
        <Route path='/products/:id' exact component={Detailedpage}/>
        {/* <Signup/>
        <Register/> */}
        <Route path='/cart' exact component={Cart}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
     );
    }
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

-----> Searchbar.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Searchbar = ({onSearchChange,onSearchProducts}) => {
     return(
          <div className='tc mt4'>
              <input onChange={onSearchChange} 
                     onKeyPress={onSearchProducts} 
                     className='searchbar w-40 pa1' 
                     type='search' 
                     placeholder='Search'/>
         </div>
        );
       }

export default Searchbar;
```

-----> Detailedpage.js (Ignore the specs and all that stuff I've written in the list-item and p tags)

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addProductToCart} from '../../Actions/Actions';
import './Detailedpage.css';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        products : state.cartReducer.products
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addProductToCart : (product) => dispatch(addProductToCart(product))
    }
}

const Detailedpage = (props) => {
    const {products,addProductToCart} = props;
    const product = products.find((phone) => {
        if((phone.pid) === Number(props.match.params.id)){
            return phone;
        }
        return null;
    });

console.log('mapStateToProps -> ',products);
const {pURL,pName} = product;
return(
    <div style={{display: 'flex',justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
        <div className='dPageImgDiv bw1 mb4'>
            <img className='dPageImg' src={pURL} alt={'phone'}/>
        </div>
        <div className='infoSide tc pb4 mb4'>
            <p className='phoneTitle fw4'>{pName}</p>
            <div>
                <ul className='details'>
                    <li>90 Hz Fluid Display</li>
                    <li>Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ 865 with 5G</li>
                    <li>Slim and Sleek Curved Design</li>
                    <li>48 MP Triple Camera</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className='overview dib fw3'>
                <p>
                The OnePlus 8 Pro is the biggest, meanest, and best smartphone OnePlus has put out 
                thus far. At least that’s what it aims to be. It features a fantastic set of cameras, 
                a big, gorgeous, 
                120 Hz AMOLED screen, the fastest possible hardware on an Android phone, and an 
                impressive battery.
                But do you need to spend $900 for it, when the OnePlus 8 delivers a similar 
                experience for $700? Well, the 8 Pro’s camera is definitely an improvement over its 
                cheaper sibling, 
                but it also has a bunch of quirks that you may or may not like.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                  <button onClick={(product) => addProductToCart(product)} 
                        className='addToCartButton' 
                        type='button'>Add to Cart
                  </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Detailedpage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use React Router to route to whatever page you want. It looks like you are already using it and have set up routes in your App.js.
You have two options. You can surround the item which will be clicked with a link:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom
```

Use it like this:

```
<Link to={`/products/${product id here}`}>
    <Item to be clicked here />
</Link>
```

Or in an onClick handler you can do the following:

```
props.history.push(`/products/${product id here}`)
```

Once you are on that page you can grab the product id from the url like this:

```
const productId = props.match.params.id
```

And use that to render the correct product